# High Sierra does not boot on a second container after reinstalling Monterey on another container

Tags: startup, dual-boot, bootable-disk

Mac Pro 4.1 (2009) + Opencore Patcher 0.6.8

M.2 SSD 500GB (2 containers: 250GB High Sierra + 250GB Monterey)

[image]

Lately I've had several warnings in Monterey about hash mismatch detected volume disk1s5. macOS should be reinstalled on this volume.

So I formatted the drive and reinstalled Monterey. At the end I installed Opencore on the EFI and Monterey everything works correctly after restoring my Time Machine backup but to my surprise High Sierra does not start, with the forbidden symbol appearing.

I booted into recovery mode to run First Aid in Disk Utility and it said everything was correct. Still not starting.

As seen in the screenshot, High Sierra exists and I can access all the files including the Finder and Downloads files of both my user and my girl:

I reinstalled Opencore on the EFI but High Sierra still shows the forbidden symbol.

[image]

Is there a way to modify something to boot High Sierra? Any suggestions would be welcome.

P.S. I have a copy of Time Machine made in Monterey and although inside I see that there is a folder for Monterey and another for High Sierra, I think that if I reinstall High Sierra from scratch I will not be able to recover the copy as it is made in a more modern version of Time Machine .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don’t post Terminal output as an image.   It cannot be indexed by the search engine.